# Xamarin Studio on Mac complains about missing 'gcc' compiler when building for iOS

Tags: ios, gcc, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to build for iOS using Xamarin Studio on a Mac but it complains about a missing 'gcc' compiler. However the compiler is there as just typing `gcc` in the terminal works fine.

The error is a below (and I did install Xcode 'Command-Line Tools'):

```
Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --cache "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/MobileCrm/obj/iPhone/DEMO/mtouch-cache" --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/MobileCrm/bin/iPhone/DEMO/MobileCrmMT28.app" -r "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/MobileCrm.Data/bin/iPhone/Release/MobileCrm.Data.dll" -r "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/MobileCrm.UI/bin/iPhone/Release/MobileCrm.UI.dll" -r "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/Resco.Data/bin/iPhone/Release/Resco.Data.dll" -r "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/Resco.UI.MonoTouch/bin/iPhone/DEMO/Resco.UI.MonoTouch.dll" -r "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/Resco.UI/bin/iPhone/Release/Resco.UI.dll" -r "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/Mono.Data.Sqlite/bin/iPhone/Release/Mono.Data.Sqlite3.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Data.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -compiler clang -linksdkonly -sdk "7.1" -targetver "5.0" --sgen --abi=armv7 "-aot=ntrampolines=2048" "-aot=nimt-trampolines=2048" "/Users/developer/Documents/lox/kmdtilsyn/MobileCrm/bin/iPhone/DEMO/MobileCrm.exe"
error MT5101: Missing 'gcc' compiler. Please install Xcode 'Command-Line Tools' component
```

Comment: The latest version of Xcode doesn't use GCC but LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

In general `gcc` is not used anymore, it's been replaced with `clang`. Newer versions of Xcode won't have `gcc`. Which version of Xcode are you using ?

Note that it's possible to **force** a specific compiler using your **project options** (check your **Additional mtouch argument**). So your application might be requiring `gcc` when your Xcode does not provide it.

Comment: Started out with XCode 5.0.x and now upgraded to 5.1.1 but same problem. There are two additional mtouch arguments speciefied in Xamarin (-aot="ntrampolines=2048" -aot="nimt-trampolines=2048").

Comment: But as I can type gcc and see that the program is there, should Xamarin not also just be able to use it?

Comment: `gcc --version` will show you that `clang` is being used (symlink). Can you add `-v -v -v -v` to your build options and pastebin the full build log. Note that the `-aot="ntrampolines=2048" -aot="nimt-trampolines=2048` arguments are not required anymore, XI will automagically compute them).

Comment: --version reveals "Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)". Do you want me to type -v -v -v -v under the additional mtouch arguments i Xamarin Studio?